# No manager for connect string

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jdbc, sqoop

As soon as my EMR-Cluster was ready to be run.

I started facing some issues when listing databases and importing sqoop

Apparently, sqoop has been installed normally and it is working normally when I type "sqoop help" in Linux terminal.

[using sqoop help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrfoo.png)

as you can see, the command could be recognized normally.

However, if I try out the sqoop import command, this one cannot be and it faces an error:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:postgres://sportsdb.cxri########.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com/SportsDB \
--username postgres \
--password mypassword \
--table addresses --target-dir s3://sqoop-table-from-rds-to-s3/sqoop-table/ -m 1 --fields-terminated-by '\t' --lines-terminated-by ','
```

[sqoop import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYtV8.png)

The same goes to the second one, which is "sqoop list-databases" as shown below:

```
sqoop list-databases \
--connect jdbc:postgres://sportsdb.cxri########.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com \
--username postgres \
--password mypassword
```

[sqoop list-databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um4AH.png)

they don't really works and anything happens ;/

I also downloaded jar and put into /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/ where is the jar files on sqoop

To do it I run these two follow commands:

```
1) wget -O postgresql-jdbc.jar https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.3.1.jar

2) sudo mv postgresql-jdbc.jar /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/
```

[Jar file added to sqoop/lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLwxc.png)

Someone else has a suggestion about what can be done in order to fix this issue?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you really need sqoop? Doesn't AWS already have an RDS to S3 backup tool builtin? Or just psql dump?

Comment: In any case, as the error says, your protocol is wrong. Needs to be `jdbc:postgresql`... I'm voting to close as a typo

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm trying out the sqoop, that is why I'm trying to use it. There are these other two options as you said, but I'd like to check this way. You're right, as soon as I checked the way of typing the error has changed at least. Now I'm facing a new issue, but I'm looking for some way to solve it

Comment: The new error that is being displayed is:

22/01/03 06:14:52 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Connection timed out.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Connection timed out.

Comment: Sounds like your firewall isn't allowing access

Comment: I made a new question with this error in here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70562492/connection-is-timed-out-in-aws

This issue with firewall could be in my PC or in the AWS environment?

Comment: Could be both, but it'd likely be the VPC config for the EMR cluster

Comment: Thank you so much @OneCricketeer. We can consider this question as answered. Coz' it was a typo. I could also understand a little what happened to VPC config or Security Group for the connection :)

Comment: Feel free to answer your own post below describing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be solved after following a tip received about a typo.

Then, I just changed the word postgres for postgresql as follows:

```
sqoop list-databases \
--connect jdbc:postgresql://sportsdb.cxri########.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com \
--username postgres \
--password mypassword
```

That is it. The issue was fixed just adjusting something pretty simple