# Connection to AWS RDS with Sqoop times out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-emr, sqoop

I'm trying to use a connection from RDS on EMR through sqoop by the following command:

```
sqoop list-tables \
--connect jdbc:postgresql://sportsdb.cxri########.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/SportsDB \
--username postgres \
--password mypassword
```

However, the connection always times out.

[image: Image 1 - Connection Timed out]

[image: Image 2 - Connection Timed out]

As I could investigate this error is related to RDS is Publicly accessible and whether inbound rules have a rule specifying myip.

My RDS is publicly accessible, but the error still persists:

[image: publicly accessible]

[image: Rule Added with myip]

Someone has some idea about what the problem is?

Comment: Is your RDS & EMR on same subnet? If yes enable `DNS Resolution` under VPC settings.
Also Is your RDS's security group allow EMR security group to connect on 5432 port?

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti thank you so much for replying to it. I could solve it by adding a rule on security group section, by enabling it to all traffic 0.0.0.0/0. As I could check in some answers in here, this way is not safe. For some reason I could just fetch data from RDS to Hadoop through sqoop doing some thing like this. Is there some other security group I could create?